# Can't Docker host more than one webserver?

Tags: linux, dns, virtual-machine, docker, dhcp

Reading [this](https://rrati.github.io/blog/2014/05/09/apache-hadoop-plus-docker-plus-fedora-issues-and-limitations/) I get the impression that a Docker container can not get a dhcp address or get a dns name.

**Question**

Does that mean that I can't host two or more webservers which both needs to listen to port 80?

Or even one webserver with a domain name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: Yes you can.

You can run as many webserver as you want and expose them with `-p 80`. The webserver inside docker will listen on 80 and docker will nat it to port 49150+.

You can also tell docker to actually listen on the 'real' port 80 with `-p 0.0.0.0:80:80`, but then you will be able to start only one. It is very common to start a reverse proxy like this and have it route to other containers via vhost for instance.

You can also run multiple webserver on the 'real' port 80 if you have multiple interfaces with `-p <ip interfaceN>:80:80`

Comment: Then what the is the point of docker if you have say an EC2 instance with only one interface, couldn't I just do the same thing with Chef or Puppet?  I don't get the container trend if you can't run more than one webserver on one interface on the same port.

Comment: How could you bind more than one webserver to a single port, whether containerized or no? As @creack said, you can use a reverse proxy and forward requests based on hostname.